# Terraform EC2 Invalid value for "path" parameter: no file exists at "userdataFile"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file

**My error**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp6BT.png)

Invalid value for "path" parameter: no file exists at "cis-userdata.sh"; this function works only with files that are distributed as part of the configuration source code, so if this file will be created by a resource in this configuration you must instead obtain this result from an attribute of that resource.

My files:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3MBj.png)
My code:

EC2.tf

```
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # ------------------------------- EC2 Module with Latest Ubuntu AMI ------------------------------------------
    # ------------------------------ No Network Interfaces. Imports Only -----------------------------------------
    # ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
      ami                     = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
      instance_type           = var.instance_type
      iam_instance_profile    = var.iam_instance_profile
      monitoring              = var.monitoring
      disable_api_termination = var.disable_api_termination
      ebs_optimized           = true
      key_name                = var.key_name
      vpc_security_group_ids  = var.security_groups
      subnet_id               = var.subnet_id
      user_data = templatefile(var.template, {
        HOSTNAME      = var.name,
        linuxPlatform = "",
        isRPM         = "",
      })

      metadata_options {
        http_endpoint               = "enabled"
        http_tokens                 = "required"
        http_put_response_hop_limit = 1
      }

      tags = {
        Creator             = var.creator
        "Cost Center"       = var.cost_center
        Stack               = var.stack
        Name                = var.name
        ControlledByAnsible = var.controlled_by_ansible
        ConfigAnsible       = var.configansible
      }

      root_block_device {
        delete_on_termination = true
        encrypted             = true
        kms_key_id            = var.kms_key_arn # Arn instead of id to avoid forced replacement.
        volume_size           = 16
        tags = {
          Creator       = var.creator
          "Cost Center" = var.cost_center
          Stack         = var.stack
          Name          = var.name
        }
      }

      lifecycle {
        ignore_changes = [
          ami,
          user_data,
          root_block_device,
        ]
      }
    }

    data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
      most_recent = true

      filter {
        name   = "name"
        values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-*"]
      }

      filter {
        name   = "virtualization-type"
        values = ["hvm"]
      }

      owners = ["xxxx"] # Canonical
    }
```

variables.tf

```
      variable "name" {
        default = "xxx-prod"
      }

      variable "instance_type" {
        default = "m5.large"
      }

      variable "public_ip" {
        default = false
      }

      variable "instance_id" {
        default = ""
      }

      variable "stateManager" {
        default = ""
      }

      variable "iam_instance_profile" {
        default = "infra-" # Required for systems manager
      }

      variable "security_groups" {
        default = ["sg-xxxx"] # 
      }

      variable "subnet_id" {
        default = "subnet-xxxx" 
      }

      variable "availability_zone" {
        default = "us-east-1a"
      }

      variable "disable_api_termination" {
        default = "true"
      }

      variable "kms_key_arn" {
        default = "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:xxxxx:key/xxxx"
      }

      variable "creator" {
        default = "xxx@xxx.com"
      }

      variable "cost_center" {
        default = "xxx"
      }

      variable "stack" {
        default = "Production"
      }

      variable "controlled_by_ansible" {
        default = "False"
      }

      variable "country" {
        default = ""
      }

      variable "ec2_number" {
        default = "01"
      }

      variable "monitoring" {
        default = true
      }

      variable "device" {
        default = "/dev/xvda"
      }

      variable "template" {
        default = ("cis-userdata.sh")
      }

      variable "key_name" {
        default = "xxx"
      }

      variable "image_id" {
        default = "ami-xxx"
      }

      variable "volume_size" {
        default = 16
      }
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Answer (score 0):

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2" {
  ami                     = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id
  instance_type           = var.instance_type
  iam_instance_profile    = var.iam_instance_profile
  monitoring              = var.monitoring
  disable_api_termination = var.disable_api_termination
  ebs_optimized           = true
  key_name                = var.key_name
  vpc_security_group_ids  = var.security_groups
  subnet_id               = var.subnet_id

  user_data = templatefile("${path.module}/${var.template}", {
    HOSTNAME      = var.name,
    linuxPlatform = "",
    isRPM         = "",
  })

  metadata_options {
    http_endpoint               = "enabled"
    http_tokens                 = "required"
    http_put_response_hop_limit = 1
  }

  tags = {
    Creator             = var.creator
    "Cost Center"       = var.cost_center
    Stack               = var.stack
    Name                = var.name
    ControlledByAnsible = var.controlled_by_ansible
    ConfigAnsible       = var.configansible
  }

  root_block_device {
    delete_on_termination = true
    encrypted             = true
    kms_key_id            = var.kms_key_arn # Arn instead of id to avoid forced replacement.
    volume_size           = 16
    tags = {
      Creator       = var.creator
      "Cost Center" = var.cost_center
      Stack         = var.stack
      Name          = var.name
    }
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      ami,
      user_data,
      root_block_device,
    ]
  }
}
```

**cis-userdata.sh** would contain the user_data for setting up the AMI as follows.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt update

cd /home/ubuntu

sudo apt-get purge 'apache2*'
sudo apt install -y apache2
sudo ufw allow 'Apache Full'
sudo systemctl enable apache2
sudo systemctl start apache2
sudo echo “Hello World from $(hostname -f)” > /var/www/html/index.html
```

For more, visit this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62599263/11145307